# PhpStorm. Скрыть файлы проекта по маске

Tags: phpstorm

Как в PhpStorm скрыть файлы по маске (пример: "*.js" and "*.js.map"). Т.е. файлы отображаемые слева в дереве файлов проекта. 
Например, в папке есть файлы: file.ts, file.js, file.js.map, так вот последние два генерируются автоматически, и никаких изменений вносить туда я не буду. Но их слишком много и они затрудняют навигацию.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы используете встроенный TypeScript компилятор, файлы, сгенерированные им, и так должны быть скрыты по умолчанию - они показываются как "дети" .ts файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, начиная с 2016.3, для таких файлов будет работать grouping просто по имени - т.е. даже если Вы их создаете с помощью неких внешних генераторов, не используя встроенные средства, они все равно будут "скрыты".
Если этого по какой-то причине недостаточно, можно создать новый scope (`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes`), исключив из него `*.js` и `*.js.map` файлы, и использовать этот scope в Project tool window вместо скоупа по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

`Settings -> Editor -> File Types`

Внизу поле для игнорирования, добавьте туда нежелательные расширения, например: `*.js;*.js.map;`

Comment: не советую... таким образом вы полностью игнорируете все javascript файлы в проекте. И можете внезапно обнаружить, что часть функциональности отвалилась - скажем, нет поддержки любимых фреймворков, не распознаются типы из библиотек и т.п. Конечно, если в вашем проекте абсолютно все, включая используемые модули и библиотеки. написаны на typescript, тогда да...